# How to fix button position in pop up box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a pop up box with a close button on the top right that looks like this. [image] The problem is that it changes position to the center of the box when horizontal scroll is on and scrolled to the right, like this. How do I fix the button on the top right of the pop up box (div)?

[image]

My css for the button position

```
.pop > span {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    right: 4%;
}

.pop {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

My html

```
<div class="container pop ui-widget-content"><span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></span>
    ...
</div>
```

I tried changing css to this but it just puts the button outside the pop up box in the main page which is not what I want to do

```
.pop > span {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    right: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary for the popup to have vertical and horizontal scroll? That seems a bit bad UX. But if you really need it, then the inner content should have the scroll, and outer container should be with respect to which the close is positioned.

Comment: Have you try to make it `float : right;` in CSS

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar yes because the text in there could be long and have lots of rows

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL yes I tried a float: right in .pop > span {}, didn't work

Comment: Can you provide the popup container element that has the width set.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar its added in question now

Comment: Then below answer should work. Did you give position absolute? Dont give position relative to pop. Just use the span css below.

Comment: I do not know why but that answer does not work

Answer (score 2):

```
.pop {
    position:relative;
}
.pop > span {
    position:absoltute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

you are right the float wont work just like that but [here is how I make it work fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diego_carrascal/3p32h37x/) :

HTML:

```
    <div class="popCont">
    <span><i aria-hidden="false" class="fa fa-times fa-lg">X</i></span>
    <div class="container pop ui-widget-content">
        <div id="codeDiv">this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test</div>
       <p>
       This is a test
        5456456456456456 64564gf56d4sgf56 sr4g56dfs4g56df4g6 er5g4df5s64g5df4g56 deg465es4g5d4s56g4d5s6g46dsg456 w4g56ds5gdf5sg56ds4 w56g45ds4g5sg4sd4g sd4g56d4s56g4df5s6g4 sgdfsgdfgh!!!
       </p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .popCont > span {
        padding 15px;
        margin-left: 97%;
        margin-top: 1%;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: red;
    }

    .popCont{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 20%;
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
    }

    .pop {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidde;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }

    #codeDiv{
        width: 450px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone for helping out. I ended up fixing this by following this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/84cyupb0/1/ and added another div to wrap the inner div.

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```